# Parse String using split() into JSON or Object using Javascript of JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, split

I am getting a passed a String that is in a unique format(is consistant though) that I need to be able to parse it so that I can modify pieces of it and then put it back together and pass it back as a string.

Here is the String im getting passed. The contents of it will change regularly, but each items structure will remain the same.

```
    View
{
    Name: View1;
    Image
    {
        BackgroundImage: Image.gif;
        Position: 0, 0;
        Width: 320;
        Height: 480;
    }

    Button
    {
        BackgroundImage: Button.gif;
        Transition: View2;
        Position: 49, 80;
        Width: 216;
        Height: 71;
    }

    Button
    {
        BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;
        Position: 65, 217;
        Width: 188;
        Height: 134;
    }

    Label
    {
        Position: 106, 91;
        Width: 96;
        Height: 34;
        Text: "Button";
        FontSize: 32;
        Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;
    }
    Scroll
    {
        Position: 106, 91;
        Width: 96;
        Height: 34;
        Button{
            BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;
            Position: 65, 217;
            Width: 188;
            Height: 134;
        }
        Button{
            BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;
            Position: 65, 217;
            Width: 188;
            Height: 134;
        }

    }

}
```

I think I need a recursive function that will seek out each k,v and put it into a proper Object or JSON file so that I can modify. The furthest that I have got is being able to Parse a single level and put it into an k,v object. Here is the code and the string it Parses.

modified string to work with my code(single level deep. I dropped View{} and Scroll{}):

```
var content='Image{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}Image{BackgroundImage: Image2.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button.gif;Position: 49, 80;Width: 216;Height: 71;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button.gif;Position: 49, 80;Width: 216;Height: 71;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}Button{BackgroundImage: Button3.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}Label{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: "Button";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}Label{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: "Button";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}';

        var result = content.split('}');
        result.pop();// removing the last empty element
        var obj = {Controls:{}};

        function nextProp(key) {
            /*if(obj.Controls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var num = key.match(/\d+$/);
                if (num) {
                    return nextProp(key.replace(num[0], '') + (parseInt(num[0], 10) + 1));
                } else {
                    return nextProp(key + '1');
                }
            }*/

            return key;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var key = result[i].split('{');
            var value = result[i].replace(key[0], '') + '}';
            obj.Controls[nextProp(key[0])] = value;
        }

        var initObjectList = '<div id="prePop">';
        $.each(obj.Controls, function (k, v) {
        initObjectList += '<div class="inLineObjects">' + '<div class="key">' + k + '</div><br/>' + '<div  class="value">' + v + '</div>' +'</div>';

        });
    initObjectList += '</div>';
    $('#code').append(initObjectList)
```

RETURNS:

```
{
    "Controls": {
        "Image": "{BackgroundImage: Image.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}",
        "Image1": "{BackgroundImage: Image2.gif;Position: 0, 0;Width: 320;Height: 480;}",
        "Button": "{BackgroundImage: Button.gif;Position: 49, 80;Width: 216;Height: 71;}",
        "Button1": "{BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}",
        "Button2": "{BackgroundImage: Button3.gif;Transition: View2;Position: 65, 217;Width: 188;Height: 134;}",
        "Label": "{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: \"Button\";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}",
        "Label1": "{Position: 106, 91;Width: 96;Height: 34;Text: \"Button\";FontSize: 32;Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;}"
    }
}
```

My problem is that the above doesnt allow me to a). target anything iside the {} because its all a value and b). it doesnt have any type of recursive ability to deal with the multiple levels i.e. View>button>scrollview

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your data (at top) looks similar to JSON. Why not use JSON?

Comment: I know..Serious. The problem is that this string is being generated by another system we have. And there are subtle differences. Any ideas how to get it into proper json? I have been messing with this for days.

Comment: A recursive approach will probably be needed. How many levels of nesting are you potentially faced with?

Comment: What is the server-side language involved? It can likely output JSON for you.

Comment: @JayBlanchard this all needs to be done client side using JS

Comment: @LeeTaylor at this time, the max amount of levels is 4 at this time.Thanks again for the help.

Comment: It's almost JSON. I guess it can be converted with two regular expression replaces.

Comment: Do you need to parse this into a structure, or is there specific data you need to extract from it?

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes. ideally it stays in a similar structure where I can target any k,v at any level. Once its broken down, I have to create and populate a form for the given target. for example if I targeted 'Button' it would loop through and create a form and populate the form with the values so that i can edit them, and then save them back to the object.

Comment: a recursive descent parser would be easy to write for this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: You can either do it in very complicated manner or just break it in lines, add a ':' before every opening braces. Split lines containing ':' with ':' and double quote both sides (this will work if you get above format everytime).

Comment: @akonsu I have to do it in js. Not sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: @Rob, it can be done in js, yes. Define a grammar for your input. Then as the wikipedia article suggests write a procedure for each production in the grammar and build your expression tree (or the final structure) inside these procedures.

Comment: @specialscope can you provide an example of using multiple splits? Also,it will be delivered to me in a block, not broken down into lines. does that matter?

Comment: yes it does. In that case (considering a statement always ends with a semicolon) you can read character by character and do special processing whenever you encounter {,:,;. If the data becomes too complicated you are better off implementing a parser. This somehow might be little tough for javascript only.

Comment: You said : `The problem is that this string is being generated by another system we have.` could you post EXACTLY how the string is generated? ... also, does it have always the same format/structure? ... or is (will be) what you posted inside of `var content`?

Comment: @wvxvw all I need to do at this point is store values. There will not be any functionality dependant on it. i.e. Transition. The flow is 1). I get passed the above string(var content) 2).I need to break it down and load it into a form where I can target and modify any value(not key).3) I will load it into a form incase any values need to be modified. 4) save the modified values back into the object. 5). eventually convert it back into a string and pass it back into the system that gave it to me. Unfortunately, I cannot have the other program modify its structure.

Comment: Are you referring to the current output? Its currently k="Button", v="{all the stuff}". This is wrong in my code because I cant target anything inside v. You can think of View1 as just another simple piece of data. You dont have to treat it any different that width: 10. Another layer of the application has the logic for what value can go where. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: - The problem is that the string that im bringing in, was not originally intended to be an object. It apart of another program that uses this structure as an instructions script. For example Text: "Button" is because its identifying that it need to print what ever is in the "" onto the button, where as Name: View1 is assigning it an id. Here is another posting i made that better shows you what im trying to do. At the end of the day, I just need to edit the values in this and then put it back  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062326/javascript-object-into-list-and-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
str = str.replace(/(\w+)\s*\{/g, "$1:{"); // add in colon after each named object
str = str.replace(/\}(\s*\w)/g, "},$1"); // add comma before each new named object
str = str.replace(/;/g, ","); // swap out semicolons with commas
str = str.replace(/,(\s+\})/g, "$1"); // get rid of trailing commas
str = str.replace(/([\d\.]+(, [\d\.]+)+)/g, "[$1]"); // create number arrays
str = str.replace(/"/g, ""); // get rid of all double quotes
str = str.replace(/:\s+([^\[\d\{][^,]+)/g, ':"$1"');  // create strings

var obj;
eval("obj={" + str + "};");

alert(obj.View.Scroll.Button.Width);
```

The only problem with this is that your pseudo JSON doesn't have unique property names.  For example, you have two `Button` properties under `View`.  I'm not sure how you want to handle fixing that, although you could do it with another regular expression.  But this should at least solve your initial object creation problem.

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T59fL/1/) if you want to see it in action.

Comment: I think this will work. What about if the string is delivered without /n line breaks.

Comment: None of the regular expressions are using `\n`, instead they are using the more generic `\s` so this will work without the newline characters.

Comment: This works great. As far as identifying duplicate properties. if I call var str I see the multiple Buttons, but if I call var obj it only capture the last Button and removes the first. Is there anything you can add to the solution to prevent this? Maybe add an index or random field to it?

Answer (score 1):

```
function generalizeFunnyformat(raw) {
    "use strict";
    return ",;:{}".indexOf(raw) > -1? raw :
        " \t\r\n".indexOf(raw) > -1? " ": "a";
}

function infer(value) {
    "use strict";
    if (/^\d/.test(value)) {
        return parseFloat(value);
    } else if (/["']/.test(value)) {
        return value.substr(1, value.length - 2);
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}

function tokenEnd(state, first, second) {
    "use strict";
    state.token += first;
    if (!state.meta) {
        if (state.cursor &&
            state.cursor.hasOwnProperty(state.token)) {
            // This may be overly confident. What if primitives are also
            // allowed at the same nesting level?
            // Here we hope that coursor will be adjusted by bracket()
            // but if it doesn't happen, then we are lost.
            if (!(state.cursor[state.token] instanceof Array)) {
                state.cursor[state.token] = [state.cursor[state.token]];
            }
            state.extra = true;
            state.cursor = state.cursor[state.token];
            state.meta = state.cursor.length;
        } else {
            state.cursor[state.token] = null;
            state.meta = state.token;
        }
    } else if (state.appending) {
        if (state.cursor[state.meta] instanceof Array) {
            state.cursor[state.meta].push(state.token);
        } else {
            state.cursor[state.meta] =
                [state.cursor[state.meta], infer(state.token)];
        }
    } else {
        state.cursor[state.meta] = infer(state.token);
    }
    state.token = "";
}

function space(state, first, second) {
    "use strict";
    // noop
}

function token(state, first, secon) {
    "use strict";
    state.token += first;
}

function bracket(state, first, secon) {
    "use strict";
    var newCursor = { };
    state.cursor[state.meta] = newCursor;
    state.parents.unshift(state.cursor);
    state.cursor = newCursor;
    state.meta = "";
}

function close(state, first, second) {
    "use strict";
    state.cursor = state.parents[0];
    state.parents.shift();
    if (state.extra) {
        state.cursor = state.parents[0];
        state.parents.shift();
    }
    state.extra = false;
    state.appending = false;
}

function comma(state, first, second) {
    "use strict";
    state.appending = true;
}

function colon(state, first, second) {
    "use strict";
    state.appending = false;
}

function semi(state, first, second) {
    "use strict";
    if (state.token) {
        tokenEnd(state, "", second);
    }
    state.meta = "";
    state.appending = false;
}

function error(state, first, second) {
    "use strict";
    throw "Invalid character sequence: " + second +
        " cannot follow " + first;
}

function llparseFunnyFormat(source) {
    "use strict";
    var iterator, len = source.length - 1,
        first, second, genFirst, genSecond, handler,
        state = { result: null, cursor: { }, appending: false,
                  token: "", meta: null, parents: [], extra: false },
        parseTable = { "  ": space,
                       " :": space,
                       " a": space,
                       " ,": space,
                       " }": space,
                       " ;": space,
                       " {": space, // space
                       "aa": token,
                       "a ": tokenEnd,
                       "a:": tokenEnd,
                       "a;": tokenEnd,
                       "a{": tokenEnd,
                       "a,": tokenEnd,
                       "a}": error, // token
                       "{ ": bracket,
                       "{a": bracket,
                       "{}": bracket,
                       "{,": error,
                       "{:": error,
                       "{;": error,
                       "{{": error, // bracket
                       "} ": close,
                       "}}": close,
                       "}a": error,
                       "};": error,
                       "},": error,
                       "}:": error,
                       "}{": error, // close
                       ",,": error,
                       ",a": comma,
                       ", ": comma,
                       ",;": error,
                       ",:": error,
                       ",}": error,
                       ",{": error, // comma
                       "; ": semi,
                       ";a": semi,
                       ";}": semi,
                       ";,": error,
                       ";:": error,
                       ";;": error,
                       ";{": error, // semicolon
                       "::": error,
                       ":a": colon,
                       ": ": colon,
                       ":,": error,
                       ":;": error,
                       ":{": error,
                       ":}": error
                     };
    state.parents[0] = state.cursor;
    state.result = state.cursor;
    for (iterator = 0; iterator < len; iterator++) {
        first = source[iterator];
        second = source[iterator + 1];
        genFirst = generalizeFunnyformat(first);
        genSecond = generalizeFunnyformat(second);
        handler = parseTable[genFirst + genSecond];
        handler(state, first, second);
    }
    return state.result;
}

var test =
"View" +
"{" +
"    Name: View1;" +
"    Image" +
"    {" +
"        BackgroundImage: Image.gif;" +
"        Position: 0, 0;" +
"        Width: 320;" +
"        Height: 480;" +
"    }" +
"" +
"    Button" +
"    {" +
"        BackgroundImage: Button.gif;" +
"        Transition: View2;" +
"        Position: 49, 80;" +
"        Width: 216;" +
"        Height: 71;" +
"    }" +
"" +
"    Button" +
"    {" +
"        BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;" +
"        Position: 65, 217;" +
"        Width: 188;" +
"        Height: 134;" +
"    }" +
"" +
"    Label" +
"    {" +
"        Position: 106, 91;" +
"        Width: 96;" +
"        Height: 34;" +
"        Text: \"Button\";" +
"        FontSize: 32;" +
"        Color: 0.12549, 0.298039, 0.364706, 1;" +
"    }" +
"    Scroll" +
"    {" +
"        Position: 106, 91;" +
"        Width: 96;" +
"        Height: 34;" +
"        Button{" +
"            BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;" +
"            Position: 65, 217;" +
"            Width: 188;" +
"            Height: 134;" +
"        }" +
"        Button{" +
"            BackgroundImage: Button2.gif;" +
"            Position: 65, 217;" +
"            Width: 188;" +
"            Height: 134;" +
"        }" +
"" +
"    }" +
"" +
"}";

llparseFunnyFormat(test);
```

The above is a fair LL(1) parser for what I could understand from your example. It looks like it does what you need, but it may be rough around the edges. Especially you may want to work on the `infer()` function to make a better inference of the data type it contains.

It also doesn't use `eval()` - which you obviously don't want to use in the data obtained through RPC.

Also, if you look into the `parseTable` you will see how badly the grammar was designed for this format. It has too many invalid products (even JSON is better!). So it would make total sense to ask the person who is providing you with this data to just use JSON, because what they made is certainly worse.

**EDIT:** Updated the code to aggregate identically named keys into arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Okay this should work. Follow exact steps.

> 1. Remove whitespaces and linebreaks.
> 2. Replace semicolon with ;"" (semicolon,dblquote, dblquote)
> 3. Replace colon with ":" (double quote colon dblquote)
> 4. Replace opening brace with :{"
> 5. Replace closing brace with }"

You should be done.

Comment: You would also need to cope with commas between braces, etc.

Comment: The primary purpose of this is to be able to generate, target, modify the string via a web form. Once its been modified, its going to be converted back into this original format and passed back. If there is a better way to target the k,v im all ears.

Comment: @specialscope could you assist with that code? I can give it a try.